# Can't send a list of items to backend to be removed from a list

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

User is going to choose few items to be removed from a list.

I have two options, either pass the id of selected items or their objects' addresses in memory.

First question is that, is it a correct approach to send the objects of selected items rather than their ids?

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="${item}"/> 

   rather than

  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="${item.id}"/>
```

If I should send the ids of items, when I pass their IDs, create an object and set the ids I am not able to remove them from the list,  whats the best approach ?

```
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setID(selectedItems.get(0));

        Basket basket = (Basket) session.get(Basket.class, Long.parseLong(basket_id));
        basket.getItems.remove(item); <<I cant remove them by just setting their ids!!

        session.update(basket);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `list.remove` method removes first occurrence of the specified element from the list. Below block of code is copied from `ArrayList` source code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                    // REMOVE ITEM FROM THE LIST
                }
}
```

which uses the `Object.equals` method to check the equality of the object to be removed from the list. So you need to override the `equals` method in `Item` class to tell which all `items` are equal. And when you override `equals()`, you always need to also override `hashCode()` so the two methods are consistent

Now when passing an instance of `Item` to remove from the `list`, you need to set the values of all the properties of `Item` that were used to implement the `equals` method.

But you should not use the `database identifier (id)` to implement the `equals()`. Hibernate doesn’t assign identifier values until an entity is saved. So, if the object is added to a `Set` before being saved, its hash code changes (on save action) while it’s contained by the `Set`, contrary to the contract of `java.util.Set`. You could use a combination of properties, that is unique for each instance of `Item`.

Comment: thanks, entities have been already persisted in the database, I need to remove those that user choose. does that mean if 10 different items have been chosen I have to retrieve the fields of all of them then perform equal method on all of them?

Comment: you don't have to retrieve them from DB. you need to create 10 items with user submitted data, set the properties needed for `equals` and pass them to `basket.getItems.remove(item);` to remove from the `list`. Now you can update the `basket` with `session.update(basket);`.

Comment: by retriving them from db I mean all items of basket, session.get(Basket.class,12), should I pass the object or just the id ? id can be used to compare as it is the same as what I have in db so why should I receive all the data? does that mean I should use the object? (first approach?)_

Comment: to retrieve `basket` from DB, you can just use the `id`. `session.get(Basket.class,12)` will load a `basket` with a list of `items`. Now to remove specific items from the `item` list, create `Item` with the properties used in the `equals` method of `Item`, pass them to `basket.getItems.remove(item)` and update the DB with `session.update(basket)`.

Answer (score 1):

Load item object before deleting.

```
Item item = session.load(Item.class, selectedItems.get(0))
```

then call

```
basket.getItems.remove(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches, If you are comfortable with hql or sql, i would prefer doing it with query,

1. Approach one

   delete from table where id in (x,y,z,xy...);

advantages: You need not load anything from the DB. You just run a sql and get the response back.

1. Approach two

Eager fetch the objects into the memory(Ofcoz, send the IDs from the client) iterate over the list of items and match the ID and remove it. Flush the session.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your class for the object to be removed, you need to `override equals() method`. code it such a way that `if all member variables are equal, then the objects are equal`. template implementations are available in Netbeans IDE which use some more checks like the instance of check.

```
Otherwise object member variables could all be same but still objects 
will not be equal since they refer to different locations in memory heap.
```

I almost invariably `override equals() and toString() methods` of my `model classes`

Answer (score 0):

simple and strightforward

do not remove the copy, search inside:

```
for(Iterator<Item> iterator = basket.getItems().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{
    Item currentItem = iterator.next();

    if(selectedItems.contains(currentItem.getId()))
    {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

however, NEVER use `value="${item}"` if you have not overridden `item.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not change your ArrayList to a HashMap and store the objects against their ID's? then you can remove them with a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Hql.

```
session.createQuery("delete from Item i where i.id in (:iids)").setParameter("iids", item_ids).executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't render objects directly.  Don't do it.  That way lies pain and madness.  Suppose you do this, and haven't overridden `toString()`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="${item}"/>
```

Then the following happens:

- You fetch items into a `List`, rendering each using the default `class.name@address` implementation of `toString()`.
- The user chooses some items to remove and submits the form, *which makes a new HTTP request*.  The original `List` of items is gone, so those addresses point to...well, you have no idea what they point to.

(There are other problems: if a malicious attacker checks the page source, they now know you're running a Java-based server.  No reason to volunteer that information.)

Now, you might think something like "hey, I'll just put those items in my session."  Now you have the same problem: most session-handling implementations will serialize the items when storing them in the session, and deserialize them *into a new copy* upon retrieval.  Your object references now mean nothing.

You could override `toString()`, but why?  Just pass the IDs and send them to your DB in the removal query.  That way, there are no surprises if someone decides to change the `toString()` implementation.